# Up to which $n$ is the search of Proth primes complete?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A number of the form $k \times 2^n + 1$ with $k < 2^n$ , $k$ odd and $n \ge 1$ is
called a Proth number. If it is prime, it is called a Proth prime.

> Up to which $n$ are all Proth primes known ?

I have looked in various databases, but I do not know if there is a database
regularly updated containing all known Proth primes or at least giving a survey,
for which $n$ all Proth primes are known.

Comment: I presume you have already looked in the OEIS http://oeis.org/A080076 and the Prime Pages http://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=66 The latter does mention such a prime confirmed earlier this year, but does not give any indication of how this thins out the field of unconfirmed Proth primes.